# Abelian group of order 155

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I am trying to prove that a group of order $155$ that is abelian must be cyclic, and since $155 = 5*31$, I think that the only choices are $\mathbb{Z}/155\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, which are isomorphic to each other by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups. However, I'm not quite sure why EVERY abelian group has to be isomorphic to a direct product of Z/nZ, or if that's even true.

Comment: Structure theorem for abelian groups : Every abelian group is the direct product of cyclic groups, whose orders are prime powers, whose product is the order of the original group (of course). The first choice is cyclic. Can you find an element of order $155$ in the second group? If so, it will be cyclic as well. Therefore the conclusion holds. the hint for the second is that $5$ and $31$ are coprime.

Comment: "However, I'm not quite sure why EVERY abelian group has to be isomorphic to a direct product of Z/nZ, or if that's even true." [It is true, and it's an important theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.